# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{4}{l}\textbf

Tags: tables

How to resolve the above mention errore

```
\begin{table}[]
 \begin{center}
\caption{Summary of sample entropy (SPE) features (M $\pm$ std)  obtained for three classes. }
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{4}{l}\textbf{SBs}  & \textbf{LRHPT (M $\pm$ Std)} & \textbf{HRHPT (M $\pm$ Std)} & \textbf{HC (M $\pm$ Std)} \\ \hline 
\textbf{1}  & 0.168$\pm$0.232 & 0.184$\pm$0.261 & 0.541$\pm$ 0.036 \\
\textbf{2}  & 1.058$\pm$0.276 & 1.109$\pm$0.192 & 1.389$\pm$0.320 \\
\textbf{3}  & 1.112$\pm$0.280 & 1.172$\pm$0.187 & 1.162$\pm$0.253 \\
\textbf{4}  & 0.985$\pm$0.214 & 1.029$\pm$0.131& 0.615$\pm$0.252 \\
\textbf{5}  & 0.837$\pm$0.168 & 0.860$\pm$0.092 & 0.327$\pm$0.186 \\
\textbf{6}  & 0.662$\pm$0.154 & 0.644$\pm$0.129 & 0.222$\pm$0.075\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \label{fig:SEmeanstd}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You're specifying eight cells in the first row.

Comment: The problem is the row `\multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{4}{l}\textbf{SBs}  & \textbf{LRHPT (M $\pm$ Std)} & \textbf{HRHPT (M $\pm$ Std)} & \textbf{HC (M $\pm$ Std)}`. I can't figure out what the table is *supposed to* look like; however, `\multirow{2}{*} &` looks like a mistake to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear how the final result should look like.

My guess is that you want “SBs” as the header of the first column. Here's a fixed version an an improved one using `siunitx` and `booktabs`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Summary of sample entropy (SPE) features (M $\pm$ std)  obtained for three classes. }
\label{fig:SEmeanstd}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\textbf{SBs}  & \textbf{LRHPT (M $\pm$ Std)} & \textbf{HRHPT (M $\pm$ Std)} & \textbf{HC (M $\pm$ Std)} \\ \hline 
\textbf{1}  & 0.168$\pm$0.232 & 0.184$\pm$0.261 & 0.541$\pm$ 0.036 \\
\textbf{2}  & 1.058$\pm$0.276 & 1.109$\pm$0.192 & 1.389$\pm$0.320 \\
\textbf{3}  & 1.112$\pm$0.280 & 1.172$\pm$0.187 & 1.162$\pm$0.253 \\
\textbf{4}  & 0.985$\pm$0.214 & 1.029$\pm$0.131& 0.615$\pm$0.252 \\
\textbf{5}  & 0.837$\pm$0.168 & 0.860$\pm$0.092 & 0.327$\pm$0.186 \\
\textbf{6}  & 0.662$\pm$0.154 & 0.644$\pm$0.129 & 0.222$\pm$0.075\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Summary of sample entropy (SPE) features (M $\pm$ Std)  obtained for three classes. }
\label{fig:SEmeanstd-SI}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.3(3)]}
}
\toprule
\textbf{SBs} &
  {\textbf{LRHPT}} &
  {\textbf{HRHPT}} &
  {\textbf{HC}}
\\
&
  {\textbf{(M $\pm$ Std)}} &
  {\textbf{(M $\pm$ Std)}} &
  {\textbf{(M $\pm$ Std)}}
\\
\midrule
\textbf{1}  & 0.168\pm0.232 & 0.184\pm0.261 & 0.541\pm0.036 \\
\textbf{2}  & 1.058\pm0.276 & 1.109\pm0.192 & 1.389\pm0.320 \\
\textbf{3}  & 1.112\pm0.280 & 1.172\pm0.187 & 1.162\pm0.253 \\
\textbf{4}  & 0.985\pm0.214 & 1.029\pm0.131 & 0.615\pm0.252 \\
\textbf{5}  & 0.837\pm0.168 & 0.860\pm0.092 & 0.327\pm0.186 \\
\textbf{6}  & 0.662\pm0.154 & 0.644\pm0.129 & 0.222\pm0.075 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `center`, that adds vertical space, but `\centering` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have to confess that I can't figure out what `\vspace{-0.3cm}` and `\multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{4}{l}\textbf{SBs}` are supposed to do. Without them, with some reshuffling of the material in the header cells of the three data columns, and with a change column type from `l` to `c` for the data columns, I get the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Summary of sample entropy (SPE) features 
(M${}\pm{}$Std) obtained for three classes.}
\label{fig:SEmeanstd}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\hline
%\vspace{-0.3cm}
%\multirow{2}{*} & \multicolumn{4}{l}\textbf{SBs} 
 & \textbf{LRHPT} & \textbf{HRHPT} & \textbf{HC} \\ 
 & (M${}\pm{}$Std) & (M${}\pm{}$Std) & (M${}\pm{}$Std) \\
\hline 
\textbf{1} & 0.168${}\pm{}$0.232 & 0.184${}\pm{}$0.261 & 0.541${}\pm{}$0.036 \\
\textbf{2} & 1.058${}\pm{}$0.276 & 1.109${}\pm{}$0.192 & 1.389${}\pm{}$0.320 \\
\textbf{3} & 1.112${}\pm{}$0.280 & 1.172${}\pm{}$0.187 & 1.162${}\pm{}$0.253 \\
\textbf{4} & 0.985${}\pm{}$0.214 & 1.029${}\pm{}$0.131& 0.615${}\pm{}$0.252 \\
\textbf{5} & 0.837${}\pm{}$0.168 & 0.860${}\pm{}$0.092 & 0.327${}\pm{}$0.186 \\
\textbf{6} & 0.662${}\pm{}$0.154 & 0.644${}\pm{}$0.129 & 0.222${}\pm{}$0.075\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```